# Styling 4 corners of block

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I had to style block corners as in this first image.

[image: image1]

I did it with help of extra inner block, using ::before and ::after pseudo-elements of both blocks:

```
<div class="header__text">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```

```
.header__text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.header__text::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.header__text::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.header__text p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: .07em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.header__text p::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.header__text p::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

[jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/dugusayibu/edit?html,css,output)

Are there any better ways to style it using only css, without extra blocks, images, other auxiliary things? Just pure css.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use multiple gradient background-images:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 12px, transparent 12px, transparent calc(100% - 12px), black calc(100% - 12px)),
    linear-gradient(90deg, black 12px, transparent 12px, transparent calc(100% - 12px), black calc(100% - 12px)),
    linear-gradient(black 12px, transparent 12px, transparent calc(100% - 12px), black calc(100% - 12px)),
    linear-gradient(black 12px, transparent 12px, transparent calc(100% - 12px), black calc(100% - 12px));
  background-size: 100% 1px, 100% 1px, 1px 100%, 1px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what i'm looking for! Such an interesting decision!